# How to Implement UNION query in symfony Prople

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, union, propel

I am using symfony v.1.4.6 (Propel) & php 5.2.6

I got one challanging situation where i have to implement the bellow query into symfony Propel
I googled it alot but i failed to find the perfect solution to implement UNION in propel

```
SELECT top 5000 filetable.sha2, finalhash.ihash FROM filetable (nolock)
JOIN finalhash (nolock) ON (filetable.finalhash_id=finalhash.id)
WHERE (
    finalhash.ihash ='1FDE08EACCC5B247026D1D3A71DDD3846E31095D3A852CCFCDF3B7EAC00FD6D1' 
) 
UNION ALL
SELECT top 5000 filetable.sha2, finalhash.ihash FROM filetable (nolock)
LEFT JOIN finalhash (nolock) ON (filetable.finalhash_id=finalhash.ID)
WHERE (
    filetable.sha2='1FDE08EACCC5B247026D1D3A71DDD3846E31095D3A852CCFCDF3B7EAC00FD6D1'
)
```

Please guide me and give suggestion to implement above query in symfony Propel :/

Thanks for all of you!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know `Propel` doesn't have support for `UNION` the way you (and me too) would want. You can do two separate queries in `Propel` and do union on php side or try to achieve what you want with `Criteria`.

Check these similar questions:

- [Propel ORM Union query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063608/propel-orm-union-query)
- [Union query with propel ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985646/union-query-with-propel-orm)
- [complex queries with propel](http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/54239/?srch=propel%20multiple%20tables)